# Defining variables in a header file c++

Tags: c++, header

So I am really new to c++. I want to define a variable in a header file:

I have it like this in my .h file:

```
#pragma once
#define x = 0x1;
```

But when I do this in my .cpp file it doesn't work:

```
#include "x.h"

int main(){
std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `#define` is a text replacement tool (so you got `std::cout << = 0x1 << std::endl;`). `constexpr static auto x = 0x01;` would define a variable.

Comment: whatever resource you are using to learn you should stop using it. `#define x = 0x1;` is not defining a variable. Seems like you could use a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't work?

Comment: You can use `#define x 0x1` but that's a very bad idea. `#define` is used in special cases, for example different builds. At this level you should stay away from it.

Comment: Why do you think that its being in a header file is part of the problem?

Comment: "doesn't work" needs elaboration. In what way? What is the error message?

Comment: You've defined a preprocessor macro.  You did not define a variable, which would look like: `int x = 0x01;`.  In general, headers are used for **declarations**, not for **definitions**.  In this case, your header would **declare** `extern int x;` and elsewhere in some source file you'd **define** `int x = 0x01;`.

Answer (score 0):

always defines variables that are global or const like

```
const int VARIABLE = 1;
```

then you can easily do

```
std::cout << VARIABLE  << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not variables defined in the header file. they are macros.

**Macros**: Macros are a piece of code in a program that is given some name. Whenever this name is encountered by the compiler the compiler replaces the name with the actual piece of code. The `‘#define’` directive is used to define a macro. Lets understand the macro definition with the help of a program:

```
#include <iostream>

// macro definition
#define size 5
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

whenever you use `size` compiler replaces it with 5

```
#define x 0x1
```